# Shopify Metafield List of Images

Tags: list, image, shopify, liquid

I need to get the list of images (files) from my metafield in Page.
I'm using this logic but it is not working...

```
`<div class="swiper ts-editorial-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  {% for custom.photography in page.metafields.custom.photography %}
   <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="{{ page.custom.photography }}"></div>
   {% endfor %}
  </div>
 </div>`
```

Please, what is the correct form of doing this?

Thank you

Also tried to create a variable of the list. But didn't work.